# Vertex enumeration for polytope with a sparse halfplane description?

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

Say I have a (bounded convex) polytope $P\subset\mathbb R^d$ with description $Ax\le b$, where $A$ is *sparse* in the sense that there are at most $k$ nonzero entries in each row or column, where $k$ is fixed (while $d$ may be large). In other words, $P$ is defined by linear inequalities which each involve few coordinates, and each coordinate appears in few inequalities. (In the specific example I'm currently thinking about, $k=3$.)

What is a good algorithm to find the vertices in this situation? What is known about the complexity (for $d\to\infty$ while $k$ is fixed)? I'm also interested in any theorems characterizing the vertices of such a polytope.